# Create own list style caracal rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openxml, caracal

I use caracal gem to create docx file from template.

In template I need list which looks like this:

1. List item
   1.1 Second lv
    1.1.1 third lv

In documentation I found way how create own list style.
I put this at the beginning of the template (example.docx.caracal)

```
docx.list_style do
  type    :ordered    # sets the type of list. accepts :ordered or :unordered.
  level   3           # sets the nesting level. 0-based index.
  format  'decimal'   # sets the list style. see OOXML docs for details.
  value   '%1.%2.%3.' # sets the value of the list item marker. see OOXML docs for details.
  align   :left       # sets the alignment. accepts :left, :center: and :right. defaults to :left.
  indent  400         # sets the indention of the marker from the margin. units in twips.
  left    800         # sets the indention of the text from the margin. units in twips.
  start   1           # sets the number at which item counts begin. defaults to 1.
  restart 1           # sets the level that triggers a reset of numbers at this level. 1-based index. 0 means numbers never reset. defaults to 1.
end
```

and my lict code looks like this:

```
docx.ol do
  li 'text'
  li do
    text 'text'
    ol do
      li 'text'
      li do
        text 'Lorem'
        ol do
          li 'text
        end
      end
    end
   end
end
```

What I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer:

I should define style list for each level like this:

```
docx.list_style do
  type :ordered   
  level 0
  format 'decimal'
  value '%1.'
  left 360
  indent 180
end
docx.list_style do
  type :ordered   
  level 1
  format 'decimal' 
  value '%1.%2.' #show number like 1.1
  left 720
  indent 360
end
docx.list_style do
  type :ordered   
  level 2
  format 'lowerLetter' # can use decimal, lowerLetter or lowerRoman
  value '%3.' # show me only letter
  left 720
  indent 540
end
```

I hope that it will help someone

Comment: Wojtek, Your code helped me a lot. I hate using ms-word. I have to produce meeting minutes in a three level nested listing and just started using caracal. OOXML is not well documented. So, many thanks!!!